# C++ Builder XE2: Color2RGB not found

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, c++builder-xe2

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg.TGIFColorMap.Color2RGB) for the function `TGIFColor Color2RGB(TColor)` should be in the `Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg.hpp` source file. But when I try to use it I get the error `Call to undefined function 'Color2RGB'`. Here is a short example:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg.hpp>
#pragma hdrstop
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)


TGIFColor TestRGB(TColor fColor) {

   TGIFColor RGBColor = Color2RGB(fColor);
   return RGBColor;
}
```

Can anyone explain how to call this function, because the documentation doesn't!?

// Thanks

PS. I did started the question with "Hello, " but even when I edit the question it is removed :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the documentation again more carefully. `Color2RGB()` is not a standalone function like you are trying to use it as.  It is a static method of the `TGIFColorMap` class instead, eg:

```
TGIFColor TestRGB(TColor fColor)
{
    TGIFColor RGBColor = TGIFColorMap::Color2RGB(fColor);
    return RGBColor;
}
```

Comment: Well, I had no idea what __classmethod was, I thought it was yet another Delphi mumbo-jumbo trick. Well you learn something new every day, just another version of a static declaration (why can't C++ just be C++) :)

Comment: `__classmethod` **is** "yet another Delphi mumbo-jumbo trick", actually. It is a C++ compiler extension that indicates the method has a `this` pointer that points at the class type instead of an object pointer.